# Migrating MUI effects from V4 to V5 for `select` component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have the code below which had the right styles applied (especially the effect when drop-down in open). However, the same is not working with V5 version of MUI (origially it was written in V4)

```
<TextField
          className='user-input-select-field'
          select
          name={name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}
          id={name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}
          label={name + `${formItemData['required'] ? ' *' : ''}`}
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
          SelectProps={{ native: true, defaultValue: '' }}
          size='small'
          variant='filled'
          // sx={{ width: 1 }}
          helperText={
            errors[name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()]
              ? 'Required. Please select an option'
              : null
          }
        >
          <option value='' data-default disabled>
            {' '}
            Please Select
          </option>
          {formItemData['options']?.map((item) => (
            <option value={item} key={item}>
              {item}
            </option>
          ))}
</TextField>
```

I observe differences in the `classes` that get applied to the `div` & the `select`. BElow are the details

With V4, the classes applied to `div` were as below

```
MuiFilledInput-root MuiFilledInput-underline MuiInputBase-root MuiInputBase-colorPrimary MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInputBase-sizeSmall MuiSelect-root css-1u1a52w
```

With V5, the classes applied to `div` were as below

```
MuiFilledInput-root MuiFilledInput-underline MuiInputBase-root MuiInputBase-colorPrimary MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInputBase-sizeSmall css-18oaxu4-MuiInputBase-root-MuiFilledInput-root
```

The difference is that in V5 , there is no `MuiSelect-root` anymore (seems to be intentional as explained here [Github-link](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/30225)) and the CSS-classname has some MUI reference now `css-1u1a52w` vs `css-18oaxu4-MuiInputBase-root-MuiFilledInput-root`

It is almost same with the `select` element as well.
With V4, the classes applied to `select` were as below

```
MuiNativeSelect-select MuiNativeSelect-filled MuiFilledInput-input MuiInputBase-input MuiInputBase-inputSizeSmall css-11fo9j
```

With V5, the classes applied to `select` are as below

```
MuiNativeSelect-select MuiNativeSelect-filled MuiInputBase-input MuiFilledInput-input MuiInputBase-inputSizeSmall css-1gobb8q-MuiNativeSelect-select-MuiInputBase-input-MuiFilledInput-input
```

CSS-classname is the one that is different.

I have a feeling that this may be something to do with `MuiSelect-root` not being there anymore but I cannot fix the issue.

I am completely new to MUI & not sure if the above info makes sense or something else is needed to make the issue clearer. I looked into migration guide as well but it is not very clear for me. Please guide.